# Different padding input and button in Firefox

Tags: html, css, input, padding

I have a search input field and a submit button direct beside the input field. They have the same padding, but Firefox adds 1px to the button padding, but not to the input padding. Line-height makes it worse. Has anyone a solution for this?

```
.form,
button {
padding: 5px;
font-size: 12px;
border: 1px solid black;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

<input type="text" class="form" placeholder="Text" /><button class="button">Click</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r5y7byag/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix it

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
```

Including the border rule above is necessary for buttons to look the same in both browsers.

It also removes the dotted outline when the button is active in Firefox.

To fix it on the input elements aswell add:

```
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5y7byag/7/)

CSS:

```
.form,
 button {
 font-size: 12px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 line-height:30px;
 padding-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: Just padding-left. And to control the padding-top and bottom you use line-height. A good solution too.